# Why I'm not able to debug twig templates? sites/default/files/php directory is empty

Tags: theming, 8, debugging

As in question. I'm following this tutorial: https://dev.acquia.com/blog/debugging-drupal-8/debugging-twig-templates-in-drupal-8-with-phpstorm-and-xdebug/25/08/2016/16586

but directory

> sites/default/files/php/twig

is always empty

I'v tried cr all, checked file system page, did drush cron, checked theme page - no errors.

I got some errors related to permissions at theme settings page, but:

> chmod 777 -R sites/default/files

seems to solved those.

Any advices?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the directory `sites/default/files/php/twig` is empty because the container parameter `twig.config.cache` is set to false.

The approach used in the linked article is arguable.. put a breakpoint in every twig compiled template is not a viable solution. For debugging twig templates with xdebug there are better alternatives:

- use the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module + <del>[this patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2788089)</del> (Committed)
- use the [twig_xdebug](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_xdebug) module